# Use semaphores to synchronize shared memory

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore, shared-memory

I have the following code which works fine with the sleep time. But I want to remove sleep and use semaphores to synchronize the threads ( so that the reader waits till data is available in shmptr.) How do I do that? What do I use: 

 sem_t mutex or

 pthread_mutex_t mutex? 

 P.S : I tried using both above options separately (not shown in above code though)  but didn't get desired result.Most of the times I was getting error in shmget in reader - "shmget in reader: No such file or directory".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <errno.h>



void *write(void *t)
{   char str[100]  = "\0";
    char str1[50];
    key_t key;
    char *shmptr;
    int shmid;
    if( (key = ftok("shmSemphore.c",'B')) == -1)
    {
        perror("ftok in writer");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    if( (shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
    {
        perror("shmget in writer");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    shmptr = shmat(shmid,0,0);
    if( (shmptr == (char *)(-1)))
    {
        perror("shmget in writer");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    printf("ENter your text :- ");
    //scanf("%s",str);
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);   
    strcpy(shmptr,str);
    sleep(2);
    shmdt(shmptr);
    if( shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1 )
    {
        perror("shmctl");
        exit(-1);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *read(void *t)
{   sleep(2);
    key_t key;
    char *shmptr;
    int shmid;
    if( (key = ftok("shmSemphore.c",'B')) == -1)
    {
        perror("ftok in writer");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    if( (shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("shmget in reader");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    shmptr = shmat(shmid,0,0);
    if( (shmptr == (char *)-1))
    {
        perror("shmget in writer");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    printf("your text:- %s \n",shmptr);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t reader,writer;
    int rt;
    long t = 0;
    rt = pthread_create(&writer,NULL,write,(void *)t);
    /*if(rt == -1)
    {   perror("writer thread");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }*/
    rt = pthread_create(&reader,NULL,read,(void *)t);
    /*if(rt == -1)
    {   perror("writer thread");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }*/
    pthread_join(writer,NULL);
    pthread_join(reader,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error did you get? “it doesn't work” and “there was an error” aren't error descriptions.

Comment: The error might be coming because of some mistake I might be making (or I dont know). All I want to know is simply how does one synchronize the threads? I am NOT seeking answer to the errors I might be making when I tried to synchronize them.

Comment: @FUZxxl I also edited the code for the error I was getting.

Comment: Why do you use shared memory segments when programming with threads? This is useless, simple `malloc` would do.

Comment: I agree.. but it is the lab exam I am preparing for. and I will have to use sharedMemory and synchronization using semaphores.

Comment: I was able to synchronize them using volatile int, but I need to know the semaphore way.

Comment: I do not see semaphore in your code.

Comment: "No such file or directory" is a description of `ENOENT` error code. In case of [shmget](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget) this error means that `No segment exists for the given key, and IPC_CREAT was not specified.`. It is possible, if reader executes `shmget` before writer. You need to create segment before creating the threads.

Comment: shm*() are quite useless here: we use it for Inter *Process* communication, but here everything is in the same process.